# Reac Hook Form - Botão de submit só ativa quando aperto tab ou clico fora dos inputs

Tags: javascript, react

Mesmo colocando a senha ele só ativa o botão de enviar quando eu clico fora do input ou aperto tab.
Por que isso está acontecendo? Como posso corrigir?

```
const {register, handleSubmit, formState:{errors, isValid} } = useForm({mode:"all",});

<input 
  {...register("password", {
    required: "Insira sua senha",
  })}                        
  type="password"
  id="password"
  name="password" 
  placeholder="*********" 
  value={password}
  onChange={text => setPassword(text.target.value)}
/> 
<button
  disabled={!isValid}
  type="submit">
  Enviar
</button>
```

Comment: Experimente usar `onChange` ao invés de `all` no `mode`

Comment: quando eu removo as linhas de value e onChange do input funciona direito. mas eu preciso usar eles nesse input.

Comment: Ah, você está disputando com a biblioteca sobre quem controla o input... Deixe a biblioteca cuidar disso e obtenha o valor com `watch` ou `getValues`,  dependendo da sua necessidade. Se só precisa do valor no submit, o `handleSubmit` passa como argumento pra sua função